# u8glib: how to change the number of calls to the draw() function in picture loop

Tags: c

u8glib picture loop contains a do-while loop in the following format

```
// picture loop
u8g.firstPage();  
do {
     draw();
} while( u8g.nextPage() );
```

The reference manual specifies that

> "The decision on the number of parts and the number of   calls to the draw() procedure is left to the low level driver. So there is a loop instead of explicit calls:"

As far as I understand, lower level drivers decide on multiple draw called based on the assumption that microcontroller RAM is limited. In my case I've got enough RAM and would need to execute the draw() function in a single call.

Is there any configuration that I can change in u8glib which will enable this?
Or, should I avoid doing it? why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, however some drivers have a 2x or 4x postfix, denoting the double or quad RAM buffer usage.

Oliver